# Tools to assist with upper-division grading?

Tags: teaching, grades

Are there any commercial or free products that assist professors with grading students? I've seen many K-12 solutions, but these are generally without robust curve options. I've seen a lot of professors that have created their own Excel spreadsheets, but I'd like to offer something a little more standardized.

[Easy Grade Pro](http://easygradepro.com/) and [Gradekeeper](http://www.gradekeeper.com/) are time-tested K-12 tools, but lack extensive curve-based grading options, like weighting, adjustments for curve compliance (ability to bump grades up but only if you're still within the curve), midterm grades only counting if they help the student, and the ability to switch to P/NP if the student is in a program that isn't included on a curve.

Some of these may be very specific to my institution, but I'm looking for a starting point at least.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! Could you perhaps provide links to some of those options, and maybe talk a little bit more about the "robust curve options" you're looking for? It would improve the ability of people to answer your question (one which I'm also interested in!).

Comment: I've never found anything _except_ Excel (or its clones) that does everything I want.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like Gradekeeper remains the go-to program. So if you want to do something more sophisticated you probably want to think about working up some macros in Excel. For example, [this post has some good example macros](http://divisbyzero.com/2008/12/22/how-to-curve-an-exam-and-assign-grades/). There were three extensive discussions of gradekeeping software on Profhacker that you might want to skim. One on [gradekeeping programs in general](http://chronicle.com/blogs/profhacker/grade-keeping-programs/22745), one on a neat iPad app called [GradeBook Pro](http://chronicle.com/blogs/profhacker/gradebook-pro-or-one-grading-app-to-rule-them-all/37942) and one that focused on a [few cloud based apps for grade keeping](http://chronicle.com/blogs/profhacker/create-an-easy-online-gradebook-with-learnboost/39272). None of these seem to really do what you want, and with any of these you probably want to talk to someone at your institution about any policies they might have, particularly for something like a cloud app or an iPhone app regarding where student grades are kept and [FERPA](http://www2.ed.gov/policy/gen/guid/fpco/ferpa/index.html).

Comment: +1 for the comment about the need for privacy. In most cases, it will probably be _verboten_ to store grades "in the cloud" without extremely strong encryption in place.

Comment: ...even _with_ extremely strong encryption in place.